# WriteLine into the text file and changes preview

Tags: c#, winforms, .net-2.0, streamwriter

Can I write line of text into file and see changes after each call `WriteLine`? Now I see changes in this file only after closing `StreamWriter`.

```
StreamWriter sw = new StreamWriter(string path);
sw.WriteLine("text");
```

in this place I want to preview my file

```
sw.Close();
```

now I see writed line only in this moment

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Output to the `StreamWriter` is buffered by default. 
Try this:

```
sw.AutoFlush = true;
```

See here http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.streamwriter.autoflush.aspx

Comment: Hmm, I tried this before, but probably I made mistake somwhere. Now it's working :)